# Context empty after async initialisation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to fetch data from a backend API and initialise my FieldsContext. I am unable to do it, it returns an empty fields array in the Subfields component. I have spent hours on fixing it. But I eventually give up. Please take a look into this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './App.css';
import Index from './components/pages/index/'

import FieldsProvider from './providers/fieldProvider'
import AuthProvider from './providers/authProvider'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import SubFields from './components/pages/subfields';

function App() {

  
  return (
    
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <FieldsProvider>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            <Route exact path="/:fieldid/subfields" component={SubFields} />
          </Switch>
        </FieldsProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**FieldsContext.js**

```
import React from 'react'



const FieldsContext = React.createContext();
export default FieldsContext
```

**FieldsProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FieldsContext from '../libs/fieldContext'


export default class FieldsProvider extends Component {
    state = {fields:[]}
    

    getFields()
    {
            fetch('/api/fields')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(fields => this.setState({fields}));
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getFields();
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <FieldsContext.Provider value={this.state} >
               {this.props.children}
           </FieldsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

**Subfields.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FieldsContext from '../../../libs/fieldContext'
import FieldsList from '../../Fields/fieldlist'
export default class SubFields extends Component {
    
     componentDidMount(){
        // const fieldId = this.props.match.params.fieldid;
        console.log(this.context);
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

SubFields.contextType = FieldsContext
```

Comment: if you place a breakpoint on `this` within `fields => this.setState({fields})` for `getFields()` what does `this` refer to?

Comment: @Gandzal this refers to an object given below
`_reactInternalInstance: Object { … }
​
_reactInternals: Object { tag: 1, key: null, index: 0, … }
​
context: Object {  }
​
props: Object { children: {…} }
​
refs: Object {  }
​
state: Object { fields: (9) […] }
​
updater: Object { isMounted: isMounted(component), enqueueSetState: enqueueSetState(inst, payload, callback), enqueueReplaceState: enqueueReplaceState(inst, payload, callback), … }`

Answer (score 0):

try using an ES6 Arrow function, which binds the function to the object instance, so that `this` refers to the object instance of the class when it is called.

When its called asynchronously, `this` will refer the the class object instance you want to update.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FieldsContext from '../libs/fieldContext'


    export default class FieldsProvider extends Component {
        state = {fields:[]}
        
        // ES6 Arrow function
        getFields = () =>
        {
                fetch('/api/fields')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(fields => this.setState({fields}));
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            await this.getFields();
        }
        render() {
            return (
               <FieldsContext.Provider value={this.state} >
                   {this.props.children}
               </FieldsContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, Try binding of your function in the class constructor.

```
export default class FieldsProvider extends Component {
    state = {fields:[]}

     constructor(props) {
        //bind the class function to this instance
        this.getFields = this.getFields.bind(this);
     }
    
    //Class function
    getFields()
    {
            fetch('/api/fields')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(fields => this.setState({fields}));
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getFields();
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <FieldsContext.Provider value={this.state} >
               {this.props.children}
           </FieldsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

As a side note: Prefer to use functional components for consuming of ContextAPI.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FieldsContext from '../../../libs/fieldContext'
import FieldsList from '../../Fields/fieldlist'

export default function SubFields (props) {

   const {
      match
   } = props;

   //much better way to consume mulitple Contexts
   const { fields } = React.useContext(FieldsContext);

   //useEffect with fields dependency
   React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(fields);
   },[fields]); 
  

    return (
      <div>
                
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't change anything. I am still getting an empty fields array

Comment: if you inspect the response from `/api/fields`, what do you get? (either through breakpoint or dev tools network tab)

Comment: I get back the data from my database, and I have verified it on Postman

Comment: can you try the functional implementation of SubFields component, at the bottom of this comment? note I added `fields` as a dependency. You might find that fields was only being updated after the component is mounted, causing it to not react to the change in `fields` after the API call. Not sure of your use case.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I am getting two console logs of `fields` array, one which is empty first and then later the filled one. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @NihirAgarwal Have you tried the functional component, for SubFields?